# Convert Bigint to Datetime SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, bigint

I have a table that has a field Report_Date.  This field is a bigint type.  I have another table that has ReportDate that is datetime type.  I want to combine data from each table, but I want the bigint converted into a datetime.

I tried `SELECT DATEADD(DD, convert(bigint, Report_Date), Report_date)` however I get the error message:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

I have also tried `SELECT DATEADD(DD, convert(bigint, Report_Date), convert(datetime, Report_date))` with the same error message result.

I expect the date time to be `2019-02-28 00:00:00.000`.

Comment: You must have some data in the table that is not a valid datetime value. We don't know what your bigint "dates" look like. Help us to help you by giving us some sample data.

Comment: Each row has a Report_Date that is in this form `yyyymmdd` one example '20190108'

Comment: If it is a bigint why are you converting it to a bigint? And you might want to take a look at the date you get back when you convert your bigint value to a datetime. Hint...it isn't what you think. You should convert it to a varchar first.

Comment: Convert it to char(8) and then to datetime.

Comment: Thank you!  I was looking through stackoverflow and trying to find a solution, hence the reason convert to bigint as my skills are still developing with writing SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example you would need to do something like this.

```
select convert(datetime, convert(char(8), 20190108))
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what you are trying to do with your DATEADD logic there.

Answer (score 1):

To cast bigint/int to datetime you firstly need to cast it to varchar. You can do it i.e. like this:

```
select cast(cast(Report_Date as varchar(80)) as datetime)
```

Comment: This works too, but used the other form.  Thank you